# How to iterate over multiple JSON responses?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want to return multiple responses from PHP to my Android device. 
In PHP I have something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $response["post"] = strip_tags($row["post_text"]);
    $response["date"] = date('D M d, Y', $row["post_time"]);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

In Logcat I get:

> {"tag":"midnightAnnouncements","success":1,"error":0,"post":"This is a test announcement!  ","date":"Sun Oct 21, 2012"}{"tag":"midnightAnnouncements","success":1,"error":0,"post":"Here is another  ","date":"Sun Oct 21, 2012"}n

These are the results of two rows. I'd like to iterate over the JSON object and get the strings for both "post"s. How can this be done in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the output in a JSON array:

```
$output = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $response["post"] = strip_tags($row["post_text"]);
    $response["date"] = date('D M d, Y', $row["post_time"]);

    $output[] = $response;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
String post;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    post = row.getString('post');
}
```

And as nneonneo pointed out, your response from server is not in correct format. You should first wrap everything in a two dimensional array and then echo json_encoded version.

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $response[$i]["post"] = strip_tags($row["post_text"]);
    $response[$i]["date"] = date('D M d, Y', $row["post_time"]);
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```